# Postgresql Service stopped running

Tags: service, server, jira, postgresql-9.6

I am running PostgreSQL v9.6 on windows 10. Today I tried using a program that uses PostgreSQL Databases and couldn't connect to it. I went to the Services menu in Computer Management and noticed PostgreSQL wasn't running. I tried to run it and received

[image: This message]

When I goto PGAdmin4 both Databases are still running however.

Comment: Turning machine off and on helps. I think that this is some weird issue with windows updates